# Erro na ViewData do controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

O que poderia está errado neste exemplo?

Não consigo fazer isso:

```
    var pessoa = new Pessoa
        (
           PessoaId = 1,
           Nome = "teste teste",
           twitter = "@teste"

        );
```

Mensagem de erro:

> 'Nome' does not exist in the current context 'PessoaId' does not exist in the current context 'twitter' does not exist in the current context

Tenho a Models

```
namespace PostGetModel.Models
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public string  Nome { get; set; }
        public string twitter { get; set; }

    }
}
```

No Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PostGetModel.Models;


namespace PostGetModel.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var pessoa = new Pessoa
                (
                   pessoa.PessoaId = 1,
                   pessoa.Nome = "teste teste",
                   pessoa.twitter = "@teste"

                );

            ViewData["PessoaId"] = pessoa.PessoaId;
            ViewData["Nome"] = pessoa.Nome;
            ViewData["twitter"] = pessoa.twitter;

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nenhuma resposte te agradou que permitisse aceitar uma delas?

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar um [inicializador de objetos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa
        {
           PessoaId = 1,
           Nome = "teste teste",
           twitter = "@teste"
        };
```

Ou criar um [construtor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para sua classe:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public Pessoa(int pessoaId, string nome, string twitter) {
        this.PessoaId = pessoaId;
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.twitter = twitter;
    }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string  Nome { get; set; }
    public string twitter { get; set; }
}
```

Com o construtor você pode criar a instância da forma que você estava usando.

Poderia chamar assim:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa
    (
       pessoaId = 1,
       nome = "teste teste",
       twitter = "@teste"
    );
```

Ou mesmo assim:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa(1, "teste teste", "@teste");
```

Um exemplo funcional:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var joao = new Pessoa(1, "João da Silva", "@joao");
        var jose = new Pessoa(
           pessoaId : 1,
           nome : "José da Silva",
           twitter : "@jose"
        );
        var joaquim = new Pessoa() {
           PessoaId = 1,
           Nome = "Joaquim da Silva",
           Twitter = "@joaquim"
        };
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public Pessoa() {} //normalmente isto não é recomendado, fiz só para criar o terceiro exemplo
    public Pessoa(int pessoaId, string nome, string twitter) {
        PessoaId = pessoaId;
        Nome = nome;
        Twitter = twitter;
    }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string  Nome { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/h3u8Su). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tGkLRm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ObjectInitialization.cs).

Answer (score 5):

A inicialização de propriedades de um objeto é feito com `{}`

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa
        {
           PessoaId = 1,
           Nome = "teste teste",
           twitter = "@teste"
        };
```

Comment: Agradeço! você resolveu a questão, o problema era que eu estava usando () e era {}

Answer (score 0):

Você não tem nenhum construtor definido para a classe pessoa, portanto você deve usar [inicializadores de propriedade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) para inicializar as propriedades do objeto.

No seu caso, ao colocar tudo dentro dos parenteses, você estava tentando fazer atribuições à variáveis que não existem, por isso recebia esta mensagem de erro.

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa()
        {
           PessoaId = 1,
           Nome = "teste teste",
           twitter = "@teste"
        };
```